# Ajax autocomplete jquery is not working when text field is not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, autocomplete

I'm working with `Ajax autocomplete for jquery` and my HTML code is

```
<input type="text" name="autocomplete" id="globalBCCAutoComplete">
```

and my `autocomplete` JS code is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var countries = [
        { value: '{contract_name}', data: 'Contact Name'},
        { value: '{user_company}', data: 'User Company' }
    ];
    $('#globalBCCAutoComplete').autocomplete({
        lookup: countries,
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
            //alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
            console.log('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
        }
    });
});
```

and it is working fine, but when I add value attribute in text field:

```
<input type="text" name="autocomplete" id="globalBCCAutoComplete" value="This is test">
```

After added value `autocomplete` is not working. What is the problem?

Comment: you need to set the value using javascript

Comment: any error in the console?

Comment: value is already set and coming from database.

Comment: @Se0ng11 no error in console..

Comment: I also tried in `jquery UI` it not working in my condition any alternative for that.

Comment: able to create jsfiddle and share it here?

Comment: @Se0ng11 yes sure why not.... wait....

Comment: @Se0ng11 I don't know where to add `autocomplete` library and js fiddle link is https://jsfiddle.net/kmqch519/2/ can you add auto complete library.

Comment: i not sure which library you been using, u can use https://cdnjs.com/, copy the link and put into the jsfiddle

Comment: i made a JSFIDDLE seems to work fine here https://jsfiddle.net/7g4nnnoz/

Comment: @Stavm text field already has value x and its not working that's the same problem I'm facing it.

Comment: sure it is, delete the x. and type C you'll see it suggests as intended

Comment: but in my condition I already have value in text field which is coming from database with this database value it should also work.

Comment: so you want to add that database value to the suggestions ? you'll have to push it into your `countries` array to be able to do that. i added a new js fiddle, have a look https://jsfiddle.net/7g4nnnoz/2/

Comment: I've database value called `John` and in front of that value I want to add my tags I want to update my value like this `John {contract_name}` text field has value `John` autocomplete is not working but when I remove the value `John` autocomplete starts working it should work with `John` value.

Comment: so you basically want the query to begin AFTER the initial value set ? like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/7g4nnnoz/3/

Comment: yes @Stavm but `John` value should not be removed.

Comment: Terrible question. Which autocomplete are you using? Provide URL? Do you _also_ have jQuery UI?  Complete your question.  I am voting to close for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the comments I understand all you want is to append the initial value set on the input to the suggestions object so it will act as a prefix.

why did not you say so ?

using your code:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="autocomplete" id="globalBCCAutoComplete" value="john">
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        let countries = [
           { value: '{contract_name}', data: 'Contact Name'},
           { value: '{user_company}', data: 'User Company' }
        ];

        //get current value from the textbox
        let initialTextValue = $('#globalBCCAutoComplete').val().trim();

        //append the value to your JSON objects.
        $(countries).each(function(key, country) {
            country.value = initialTextValue + ' ' + country.value
        });

        //the rest of your code:
        $('#globalBCCAutoComplete').autocomplete({
            lookup: countries,
            onSelect: function (suggestion) {
                console.log('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
            }
        });
    });
```

jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/7g4nnnoz/5/

---

an alternative would be ES6 arrow function with the .map() function:

```
//append the values to the json object.
countries.map( (country) => {
    country.value = initialTextValue + ' ' + country.value
});
```

Comment: it only show tags of `countries` variable not the whole text box value and `John` value could be changed into something because the `John` value is coming from database and auto suggestion will be shown 
 from `countries` variable not the whole value.