# Start autocomplete when press any keyword in input field

Tags: javascript, html

Autocomplete is not working when there is some text in input field and I want that it should work in that input field at any time when I press any keyword(e.g '#').
I am able to do the search part it is showing in the log but on page its not visible, its only visible if the input field is empty.

Comment: You may want to refer this :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45933955/ajax-autocomplete-jquery-is-not-working-when-text-field-is-not-empty

Comment: Can you please provide your code.

Answer (score 0):

you can see this example.

i think it could help you a

```
<input type="text" name="autocomplete" id="globalBCCAutoComplete" value="john">


$(document).ready(function() {
    let countries = [
       { value: '{contract_name}', data: 'Contact Name'},
       { value: '{user_company}', data: 'User Company' }
    ];

    //get current value from the textbox
    let initialTextValue = $('#globalBCCAutoComplete').val().trim();

    //append the values to the json object.
    $(countries).each(function(key, country) {
        country.value = initialTextValue + ' ' + country.value
    });

    //the rest of your code:
    $('#globalBCCAutoComplete').autocomplete({
        lookup: countries,
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
            console.log('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
        }
    });
});
```